# 19th century British moon landing

Tags: space, hard-science, spaceships, alternate-history

In the aftermath of the Monroe doctrine, the British empire decided to expand heavenward. As the nobles, captains, empiricists, electricians, and mechanics explained to the Majesty, technological advances now opened the way to new heights of colonization (literally). For example:

- [The first manned flight of a balloon in America occurred January 9, 1793](https://www.nationalballoonmuseum.com/about/history-of-ballooning/#:%7E:text=The%20first%20manned%20flight)
- Diving apparatuses had been in use for centuries, and [by 1836, proto-standardized diving suits were successfully being used to recover undersea wreckage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_diving_dress#Early_history/#:%7E:text=1836)
- [By 1856, commercial methods for refining pure aluminum existed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_aluminium)
- [The first commercially successful internal combustion engine was created by Étienne Lenoir around 1860](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_combustion_engine)
- [Solid fuel rockets were already being used in warfare, notably the war of 1812 and the Napoleanic wars ... Accuracy greatly improved in 1844 when William Hale modified the rocket design so that thrust was slightly vectored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rockets#19th-century_gunpowder-rocket_artillery)
- [Charles Babbage began to construct a small difference engine in c. 1819 and had completed it by 1822](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine#Charles_Babbage%27s_difference_engines)
- [The first wireless telephone conversation occurred in 1880, when Alexander Graham Bell and Charles Sumner Tainter invented the photophone, a telephone that sent audio over a beam of light.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless#History)

Drawing on these advances, the Crown's personal backing, and 49 years of hard R&D (spanning 1850-1899), the British rocketeers developed 5 *Shooting Star*s: massive rockets capable of landing 1000 kg each on the moon. As efficient liquid fuel engines were yet to be developed, the boosters employed gunpowder-based engines which were 'gimbaled' by sliding inhibitory rods between fuel pellets to tune their reaction rates -- not too differently than would be employed in nuclear reactors decades later. Inefficient hydrogen-oxygen combustion thrusters performed finer correction maneuvers. The entire ascent sequence and translunar orbit injection was governed by a collection of clocks, tabulating machines, and tilt-sensitive governers. However, since it would be until 1935 that radar was discovered, humans were needed to pilot the lander stage -- there was no room for unmanned tests.

The *Shooting Star*s were quite heavy in comparison to modern rockets: [with an exhaust velocity of only 800 m/s, the overall launch vehicle weighed in on the order of billions of pounds](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/817) and thus [required a mass ratio in the 10000's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation). To compensate, all 5 *Shooting Star*s were launched within a few hours of each other, and landed within a 100 yard neighborhood on the surface of the moon. While each of the landers carried some fuel needed for the return ascent, only one was specially equipped with the balloons, air-tanks, and food that would be needed for the return journey and reentry.

The launch day finally came on December 1st, 1899. Rushing to launch what they had yet produced in time for the turn of the century, all 5 *Shooting Star*s took off from the Port of London. Most ended in disaster: the first rocket's gunpowder fuel pellets had inhomogeneities that caused an explosion early in takeoff; the third rocket made it through ascent, but had a compressed gas leak that irreversibly steered it off course until the captain noticed it too late, thankfully, this was the space-vessel with reentry and landing equipment, so it simply reentered and landed in Fiji, where the captain started a cargo cult after himself; residual turbulence fields from rockets 3 and 4 steered rocket 5 off-course, ultimately crashing in Berlin and triggering an early World War I; rockets 2 and 4 successfully landed on the moon, but as the ascent lander never made it, all they could do was photophone their feat home and ask for help. Given the new war on their hands, Britain was not able to help.

Sticking to hard science, could such an alternate history of space exploration be possible?

Comment: I am not sure this is and hard science question, because strictly on the base of hard science and hard history that never happened.

Comment: Possible?? You've just written it!

Comment: @Jacob Valdez The Monroe Doctrine would not be any sort of set back for the UK.  The UK was in favor of the independence of the Spanish colonies because it opened possibilities for trade without Spanish restrictions.  So, in order to enable a few British merchants to become rich esier, the UK government helped  the creation of numerous independent nations who slaughtered people in wars with each other instead of livign peace with eachother under the Spanish crown.

Comment: VTC: This is an *impossible* [tag:hard-science] question as fulfilling that tag would require scholarly articles and authoritative references supporting the compression of scientific discovery and alternative history. ***They don't exist.*** At best you're going to get answers that *suggest* how key discoveries necessary for space flight (at the top of the list: mathematics, chemistry, and material science) could have been accelerated 100 years. And those are opinions at best.

Answer (score 1):

The following points illustrate issues to be addressed or not, and should not be taken as fundamental objections to the plot. As Jules Verne's [two Moon novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_the_Earth_to_the_Moon) (published in 1867 and 1871) famously show, it is perfectly possible to go from the Earth to the Moon and back in 19th century *fiction*. (And Jules Verne's plucky heroes did it with private money and effort, they had no need for the backing of a State.)

1. The British Empire was not a state; it had very limited decision making capability, and what little decision making capability it had never applied to the British Isles. The British sovereigns were Queens or Kings of the United Kingdom, Queens or Kings of the various dominions, and Empresses or Emperors *of India*. There was never an Empress or an Emperor of the British Empire, or an executive of the British Empire, or a budget of the British Empire.

   You may want to change all references to the Empire with references to the Parliament. That was and still is the decision making body which can allocate funds, workforce and resources.

   And it is never ever ever "the Majesty". It is His or Her Majesty, the King, the Queen, or the Sovereign.
2. The Crown is not a person; it cannot provide "personal" help. The Crown is the State, in its decision-making capacity; the regnant sovereign is not the Crown. When the British mean the person wearning the crown they say the King, the Queen, or the Sovereign; and not the Crown. When they say the Crown, they  mean the State, and never the King or the Queen.
3. The Empire most usually expanded when some private person or another arranged for some new territory through their private efforts, and the Crown, that is, the government and Parliament, accepted to administer it. (The Empire of India did occasional expand through diplomacy or, very rarely if ever, by force. But the Empire of India was not the British Empire; it had its own laws, its own budget, its own money, its own army, its own Civil Service, and so on. And it was most usually broke and wouldn't have even dreamt of space flight.)

   <sup>Yes, there was the [Boer War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Boer_War); but that is both outside the proposed time frame and a direct rebuttal to the idea that the British cared all that much about the Monroe doctrine. And it was a war between the United Kingdom, allied with Canada and Australia, and the Boer Republics; the Empire had nothing to do with it -- notably, India did not take part.</sup>
4. The launching point is extremely poorly chosen. It would be much better to launch from somewhere between 18° and 28° latitude (north or south, free choice) to match the orbital inclination of the Moon in the year chosen for the mission. It's not as if the British Empire had trouble finding a suitable place.

   And you obviously want to launch over the ocean, exactly because you don't want to rain debris over Berlin.
5. Clocks and tabulating machines don't work. The point is that nobody, not even today in the 21st century, can make a rocket engine with a precisely pre-computed thrust. The engines provide whatever thrust they provide, which is nominal thrust plus or minus some percent, and the flight computers compensate by adjusting the timing and whatever other parameters they can adjust. (Solid fuel engines are usually much more off the nominal thrust than liquid fuel engines, which usually have controlled throttling capability.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to AlexP's answer:

- You can substantially improve on gunpowder rockets with [Cordite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordite), developed in 1889.
- No details about the lunar surface are available. Missions to orbit the Moon and return with sketches and photographs will be necessary.
- The objective of landing all the vehicles within a 100-yard area on the Moon is wildly unrealistic for a first attempt, and this will be obvious to the project's engineers after some trials and development.
- Britain is likely to lose your early WWI, because it has spent so much on rocketry and thus been forced to spend less on its army and navy. The obvious risk of losing a war, should one break out, makes this project implausible.

Answer (score 0):

the mass ratio you suggest is completely unrealistic, even with modern technology. Such a huge mass ratio is merely a theoretical artifact that has no practical use. 800 m/s is insufficient to reach orbit. The Space Shuttle had a mass ratio of around 16. With more modern technology this could be improved considerably, but I doubt it could be doubled realistically. So a mass ratio of tens of thousands is fantasy. Although that does not mean it might not make a good story as most people would not fully understand the technical aspects.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_ratio#